# How to simplify this code below?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to simplify this javascript code,
but I don't have ability to do this,
plz help me, I will really appreciate it, thank you very much!

```
$(function() {
    $("#show1").click(function() {
        $("#showmore1").toggle();
    })
    $("#show2").click(function() {
        $("#showmore2").toggle();
    })
    $("#show3").click(function() {
        $("#showmore3").toggle();
    })
})
```

[2016/05/24] Here is my complete code, https://jsfiddle.net/o970b9cn/
sorry for my missing information.
I'd like to show many reviews, but it will hide the complete information first, when the user clicks on the button, to start the full text.

I tried the answer below yesterday, but it still can not run...sorry for my insufficient ability...

Comment: Here! https://jsfiddle.net/o970b9cn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use [**`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

*Selects elements that have the specified `attribute` with a value `beginning` exactly with a given string.*

```
$(function() {
  $("a[id^='show']").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('div').find('span[id^="showmore"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[id^='show']").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('div').find('span[id^="showmore"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanstc.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/cwtexyen.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300);
 *,
html,
body {
  /*font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;*/
  font-family: 'cwTeXYen', 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .2pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parents_reviews" style="background: #fff; width: 300px; text-align: center; padding: 15px 20px; border-radius: 25px;">
  <div style="color: #6bc4ea; font-size: 15px;">Two more earthquakes hit this month. They are not as bad, however. Only one person dies.Someone films the streets when the earthquakes hit. People are scared. They run in the streets.<span id="showmore1" style="display: none; font-size: 15px;">Difficult words: earthquake (when the ground moves), damage (to break), infrastructure (the roads, power supplies, and buildings that people need)</span>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="show1" style="display: block; margin: 5px 0;">(read more)</a>
</div>

<div class="parents_reviews" style="background: #fff; width: 300px; text-align: center; padding: 15px 20px; border-radius: 25px; margin-top: 30px;">
  <div style="color: #6bc4ea; font-size: 15px;">Two more earthquakes hit this month. They are not as bad, however. Only one person dies.Someone films the streets when the earthquakes hit. People are scared. They run in the streets.<span id="showmore2" style="display: none; font-size: 15px;">Difficult words: earthquake (when the ground moves), damage (to break), infrastructure (the roads, power supplies, and buildings that people need)</span>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="show2" style="display: block; margin: 5px 0;">(read more)</a>
</div>

<div class="parents_reviews" style="background: #fff; width: 300px; text-align: center; padding: 15px 20px; border-radius: 25px; margin-top: 30px;">
  <div style="color: #6bc4ea; font-size: 15px;">Two more earthquakes hit this month. They are not as bad, however. Only one person dies.Someone films the streets when the earthquakes hit. People are scared. They run in the streets.<span id="showmore3" style="display: none; font-size: 15px;">Difficult words: earthquake (when the ground moves), damage (to break), infrastructure (the roads, power supplies, and buildings that people need)</span>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="show3" style="display: block; margin: 5px 0;">(read more)</a>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/o970b9cn/1/)

Answer (score 4):

1. Give common class to each "`show<your_id>`". e.g. `showmore`
2. give some attribute to your element like `data-showid`, which contains id of toggle element.
3. For class "showmore", write click function

Like this

```
<a id="show1" class="showmore" data-showid="showmore1" >show more</a>
<a id="show2" class="showmore" data-showid="showmore2" >show more</a>
<a id="show3" class="showmore" data-showid="showmore3" >show more</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".showmore").click(function() {
            var this_button = $(this);
            $("#"+this_button.attr("data-showid")).toggle();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Don't think the extra attribute 'data-showid' is needed. You can simply use $(this).toggle();

Comment: @SanjayMaharjan $(this).toggle(); will toggle the current link / clicked element.

Comment: yup got it.. if toggle is for different element then its needed.

Comment: Here is my complete code, https://jsfiddle.net/o970b9cn/ sorry for my missing information. I'd like to show many reviews, but it will hide the complete information first, when the user clicks on the button, to start the full text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), simply you will iterate the function on each element that has the same attribute, in this case we will use class because the id should be unique.

We will give to each container (`#show1 #show2` ...) a `class` such show and make this function https://jsfiddle.net/sL3qk853/

```
$('.show').each(function (index, elem) {
    $(elem).on('click', function () {
        $(this).find('div[id^="showmore"]').toggle();
    });
});
```

If you have more than a div in the container you can specify the selected div by using [begin with selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) ( `div[attribute^="something"]` ) with a [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) , or just use [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) if you have a one div or want to make this on all the `div`s inside the `.show` container `$(this).children().toggle();` .

---

**Edit:** instead of using class and `each` you can do this

```js
$('div[id^="showCont"]').on('click', function () {
   $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left
}

div[id^="showmore"] {
  background-color: #3498db;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showCont1">
  <div id="showmore1">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="showCont2">
  <div id="showmore2">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="showCont3">
  <div id="showmore3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is my complete code, https://jsfiddle.net/o970b9cn/ sorry for my missing information. I'd like to show many reviews, but it will hide the complete information first, when the user clicks on the button, to start the full text.